# HTML Agility Pack recording errors on Optional closing tags

Tags: html, html-agility-pack

Given the following small snippet of code:

```
<ul>
    <li>An overview of blah blah.
    <li>An index of blah blah.
</ul>
```

HAP is recording an error per line stating that we need `</li>` tags even though, I believe, that these are optional and not needed.  Is there an option to have HAP not tag optional tag issues like this, or am I completely wrong here?  I am getting similiar issues with `</th>, </tr>, and </td>` tags as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to do this.  I scanned the source to HAP and there isn't any sort of prevision in there to make this happen that easily as well, though it could be done with maybe a day's work.  I'll just stick to 'tidy' first or manually not report these issues for now.